# W is a subspace of V and $w_1,...,w_n \in W$ and $a_1,...,a_n \in F$, so $a_1w_1+...+a_nw_n \in W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

i'm not sure if i've answered this question correctly/adequately. this is my attempt.

W is a subspace and $w_i \in W, i=1,...,n$

W is closed under addition, so $w_1+...+w_n \in W$

W is closed under scalar multiplication, so $a_iw_i \in W$

together the above properties imply $a_1w_1+...+a_nw_n \in W$

therefore $a_1w_1+...+a_nw_n \in W$

Comment: You should first use the second argument to conclude that $a_iw_i\in W$, and only *then* use the first argument that $a_1w_1+\ldots+a_nw_n\in W$.

Comment: so i should say since $a_i \in F$ and $w_i \in W$, $a_iw_i \in W$, then invoke closure under addition to conclude $a_1w_1+...+a_nw_n \in W$?

Comment: Exactly right.....

Comment: This is the span, essentially the way in which linear algebra generates subspaces from vectors. In algebra, this idea of generating a set/space from elements appears all over.